# How to create pull request to Magento CE 1.9?

Tags: magento-core

I found bug in core module and want create pull request with fix, but didn't find how I can do that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento Core team only have put Magento2 onto a public repository so the only way you can try and put in a pull request for a bug in the 1.x range would be to submit a bug report.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking